# Applying angular material theme to a specific component only

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

Is it possible to apply the angular material built-in theme to a specific component only?

I did:

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

In one of my component.scss file and referenced this as the styleUrl inside of component.ts file. But the styles did not apply to my angular material paginator.

Here is what the paginator looks like

[image]

As shown, the styles do not apply.

Is it something to do with the fact that I'm importing them in a component specific scss file instead of importing it in angular.json?

Comment: Try this to theme your component https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components

Comment: @Suryan sorry, that is not what I want to do, I want to use the angular material default styling for my paginator. It just isn't working, but I want to know how to make it work, not create my own theme for it

Comment: @ShaunChua "Is it something to do with the fact that I'm importing them in a component specific scss file instead of importing it in angular.json?" Have you tried this? Does it work?

Comment: There was valid answer for that but idk why author removed it https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-theming-d3w6xl?file=app/app.component.html

Answer (score 10):

You have to use the Mixins @angular/material provides instead of using a prebuilt theme.

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();

// Use the desired palette
$palette:  mat-palette($mat-indigo);
// Create the theme
$theme: mat-light-theme($palette, $palette);

// Include component specific mixin
@include mat-dialog-theme($theme);

// Or wrap inside another selector to scope the styles to only one specific component
my-component {
   @include mat-dialog-theme($theme);
}
```

Edit: This code should be in your styles.scss (the global one, not the component specific scss)

Comment: Why can't this be included inside the component specific scss?

Comment: @milorad It technically can, but you would blow up your CSS size, since you would have to include core in multiple components. You could keep core in your global SCSS and only apply the specific mixin in your component specific SCSS. If you want to share your `$theme` between multiple components, be sure to create an extra SCSS file that exposes only variables and no styles to keep your generated CSS size low. 
This approach is a bit error prone, that's why I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to make each component independent of default theme in angular is to having the import statement different for each component

As usual to have a default theme for overall application we can use that import 
(ex `@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/purple-green.css';`) 
in the main css file which is **style.css**

After that for each component we can use the other themes based on requirement.

ex: for a component named homepage we can add a different theme to the file
**homepage.component.css**

```
@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

and for other component like login we add a different theme for the page **login.component.css**

```
@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/pink-bluegrey.css';
```

This solved my issue.